# Pantum M6550NW multifunction printer driver for opensuse leap 15.5

Tags: printer

I have a Pantum M6550NW multifunction  scan and copy printer i was using on windows with its proper driver.
Now i have installed opensuse leap 15.5 on my desktop ad the printer conneted by usb cable,
yast recognise it but doesn' t have the specific driver .
The manufacturer states that the printer is linux compatible, but looking into its site only the driver for ubuntu is available.
There is something i could do to use again this printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

- `zypper install alien` on SuSE
- grab the driver from their website: https://drivers.pantum.com/userfiles/files/download/drive/Pantum%20Ubuntu%20Driver%20V1_1_106.zip
- unzip it
- in the folder it extracts, `Pantum Ubuntu Driver V1.1.106/Resources` there are two `.deb` files, run `alien -t pantum_1.1.106-1_amd64.deb` or the i386 one if you're on a 32-bit system
- `tar -C / -kxvpf pantum-1.1.106.tgz`

you may find that quite a few of these files already exist:

```
tar: ./usr/share/cups/model/Pantum/Pantum BP5100DW Series PS.ppd: Cannot open: File exists
./usr/share/cups/model/Pantum/Pantum P3500DNT Series PS.ppd
...
```

That should be okay and quite a few of them were already supported but perhaps this model just wasn't (I have a system package for Pantum myself on Debian.)

- if you want a list of the files that were installed: run:
  `tar -tvf pantum-1.1.106.tgz`
- finally unplug the printer, run: `sudo systemctl restart cups` and plug the printer in then attempt to add the printer from YaST.

Comment: I managed to generate a tar program and install it following your istructions(thank you very much indeed it solved my problem) , added the print from Yast,and selected its proper Pantum driver, everything went smooth and printing was fine. Only the scanner wasn' t working, because no driver vas found , maybe it is not included in the driver. any idea about it? Anyway i seldom use it , so it's not a big problem

Comment: You might try installing `xsane` if it's not already installed with `zypper install xsane` then run it; when it starts it should probe for scanners both directly connected and on the network. For me it even detects one one the network and I haven't even configured it before so hopefully it's as easy as that for you, too. If you search the internet for `pantum xsane` there's a bit of information about people using it with Pantum scanners out there.

Comment: intalled xsane  , problem solved , thank you very much for your help